# Out of range .csv py

Tags: python, csv, range

I am trying to extract values from .csv file the problem is i getting an error out of range when using a file with over 6000 data, however when using file with about 200
There is such an error

```
import csv

# Read the csv file and store the data in a list

data = []

with open('waves_Output_mono.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 

    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t') 

    for row in csvreader: 

        data.append(row) 

    

# Extract the x and y values from the data list  

y_values = [float(y[1]) for y in data] 

x_values = [float(x[0]) for x in data]
```

When i print the data it can print normally

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: `There is such an error` What error? We need the full traceback to know what line caused the error.

Comment: What that suggests is that you have some rows that are empty, or only have 1 item.

Comment: Likely the issue is that one of the lines in your CSV does not have a comma in it. Check the length of each row, and see if any are < 2

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\dsp0\main (1).py", line 382, in <module>  
    y_values = [float(y[1]) for y in data] 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "e:\dsp0\main (1).py", line 382, in <listcomp>
    y_values = [float(y[1]) for y in data] 
                      ~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Both y_values and x_values gives the same error

Comment: Their is no empty data in csv

Comment: Share your code and errors in the post itself as formatted text. Never in comments, as it's almost unreadable without proper formatting.

Comment: Clearly one of the values in `data` has a length of less than 2, yet you always try to access the second item: `[float(y[1]) for y in data`. So, you maybe need to filter out any data from `data` that would have this issue. That, or see what the actual value of `y` is, and see why it doesn't have the expected length. These all are very basic debugging steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try processing the data with a `for` so you can print the values:

```
for value in data:
    print(value)
    x = float(value[0])
    y = float(value[1])
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(y)
```

This is more code but can help you to identify where is the problem

Comment: Actually it worked I don't know what the difference but it worked

Comment: @ZyadMohamedSowilam there's no functional changes here that I can see, so I would think that something else is the reason for it suddenly starting to work